# Select Database from Hibernate Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hql, nhibernate-mapping

i need help. I'm using HQL but i stuck in this code and i dont know how to solve it.

```
def deposit = Deposit.executeQuery("select terminalID,deposit,created_at from Deposit")
```

i got the correct result like this

```
[[1, 1000, 2020-07-29 13:29:28.0], [0, 1, 2020-07-29 13:42:11.0], [2, 1000, 2020-07-29 13:50:08.0], [0, 1, 2020-07-29 14:03:07.0]]
```

but in view page, i can not call terminalID, deposit,created_at because of no such property

if i use

```
def deposit = Deposit.executeQuery("from Deposit")
```

i got the wrong result like this [com.dm.Bank.Deposit : ID]

```
[com.dm.Bank.Deposit : 2, com.dm.Bank.Deposit : 2, com.dm.Bank.Deposit : 3, com.dm.Bank.Deposit : 2]
```

[image]

DB Deposit : **Number is auto_increment**
[image: Deposit]

the Deposit **Result** is **different**

Database :

```
class Deposit implements Validateable{
    String number
    String id
    String terminalID
    String startDate 
    String endDate 
    String currency
    String startBalance
    String transactionDate
    String branchCode
    String transactionType 
    String transactionAmount
    String currentBalance
    String deposit
    String transactionName
    String trailer
    String corporateId
    String accountNumber
    String created_at
    String company
    
static mapping = {
        datasource 'DBTarget'
        table 'HISTORY_MUTASI'
        number column: "Number"
        id generator: 'assigned', column: "ID"
        terminalID column: "TerminalID"
        startDate column: "StartDate"   
        endDate column: "EndDate"
        currency column: "Currency"
        startBalance column: "StartBalance"
        transactionDate column: "TransactionDate"
        branchCode column: "BranchCode" 
        transactionType column: "TransactionType"
        transactionAmount column: "TransactionAmount"
        currentBalance column: "CurrentBalance"
        deposit column: "Deposit"
        transactionName column: "TransactionName"
        trailer column: "Trailer"
        corporateId column: "CorporateId"
        accountNumber column: "AccountNumber"
        created_at column: "created_at"
        company column: "Company"
        version false
        
    }
    static constraints = {
        number unique:true,generator:"increment";
    }
```

Comment: why are you excecuting a raw SQL-query against the object which is already mapped? why no dynamic finder, criteria or HQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, it is very important to understand how `executeQuery` returns.

> The executeQuery method allows the execution of arbitrary HQL queries.
> HQL queries can return domain class instances, or Arrays of specified
> data when the query selects individual fields or calculated values.
> Read more [executeQuery](https://docs.grails.org/3.1.11/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) from Grails documentation.

As I can see the result format, you have to use index-based operations.

For example, we can display the result in the view like below.

```
<g:each in="${deposit}" var="entry">
    <p>TerminalID: ${entry[0]} with the deposit ${entry[1]} issued at ${entry[2]}</p>
</g:each>
```